# Change size on encrypted partitions with partition tools

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-encryption

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

My laptop hard drive is encrypted. It seems like partition tool like Partition Wizard or Partition Master can't recognize the partition format, as it only display "unknown" or "other" in the format field. Windows Disk Management can only shrink the OS partition to ~250GB in my case, however I want to shrink it to 100GB or 150GB. Does the community know any way to shrink the OS partition to 100GB on a encrypted hard drive?

Comment: Can you not decrypt it? What is it encrypted with, TrueCrypt? You should be able to have a decryption program running transparently in the background. The problem is that the partition program needs to know the format of the partition to be able to move the data and update its file-system structures. If the volume is encrypted, then the partition program has no way to do anything with it because it is a “black box”. With a black box, all that can be done is to *move* it around, not actually shrink or expand it.

Comment: Agree, decrypt> resize> encrypt

Comment: I can't decrypt it since it's managed by IT. We use "PGP Whole Disk Encryption". This is how it works: when turning on the laptop, after BIOS checking, before launching the OS, I have to enter the passcode to be able to access the encrypted hard drive. Once passes that, it will load Windows 7 and so on

Answer (score -1):

The OS is not affected by full-disk encryption (it's decrypted on the fly before OS loads, and the partitions on the system-disk are contained within the full-disk encryption volume), so that's not the problem. You just need to do a proper defrag with consolidation to be able to shrink the partition more. Use "defrag c: /x /w", or MyDefrag's consolidation profile. However you might still need a more advanced tool like PerfectDisc if there are unmovable NTFS or system files towards the end of the of the partition, then use offline defragmentation to move those files on reboot.